# React + Nodejs with Passport.js authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, oauth, passport.js

I am using react for frontend, nodejs as backend and passport-google-oauth2 for authenticating users with googles oauth api.

When a user logs in, I create a new user or I find an existing user, set a cookie to know that the user is logged in.

The problem is in development I am using webpack development server and a node server. Therefore the cookies arent saved properly. I have tried using proxies in the development server but I haven't got it to work.

What is best practice here? Am I not supposed to use cookies?

Thanks in advance.